# How to set div to display in only one line?

Tags: css, text, html, alignment

I have a div that contains within itself logout button and username. If the username is too long, it splits it very strangely.
I want it to position itself according to the length of the name and in only one line.

Here is how it looks
[abnormal http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2456451/abnormal.JPG](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2456451/abnormal.JPG)

Here is how it should look
[normal http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2456451/normal.JPG](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2456451/normal.JPG)

I will point out, that the main.php has a div style...

```
<div id="logout"><div style="margin-top:-90px ;margin-left:740px;">
```

And the css has some rules also

```
#logout{
height:0px;
color: #404040;
padding: 9px;
font-size: 200%;
```

I have another div called #page that holds all the divs. Can I align #logout by the right border of  the #page div?

Thanks in advance,
Nils

Comment: Give the parent `div` a greater width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `margin-left: 740px`, and add `float: right`.

Alternatively, add this:

```
#page {
    position: relative;
}
#logout {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```